# Rearrange multiple ggplot order in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

I have a matrix in `R` and I am trying to create plots between first column (Y) with all other columns (`Xj j=1,...,12`). I am using the following code to do that:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20 * 13, mean = 0, sd = 1), 20, 13))

colnames(dat) <- c("Y", paste0("X",1:12))

data_def <- pivot_longer(dat, -Y)

ggplot(data_def, aes(x = Y, y = value)) +
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE, color = "red", size = 0.5, method = "loess") +
  facet_wrap( ~ name, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_classic() +

  labs(x = NULL, y = "Y")
```

which results in:
[image]

However after `X1` comes `X10`, `X11` and `X12` instead of `X2`, `X3`, etc.. How can I re arrange the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `fct_inorder` from `forcats` package:
This will keep the order as in your column!:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(data_def, aes(x = Y, y = value)) +
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE, color = "red", size = 0.5, method = "loess") +
  facet_wrap( ~ fct_inorder(name), scales = "free_y", strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_classic() +
  
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data_def$name = factor(data_def$name, 
                          levels = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12"))

ggplot(data_def, aes(x = Y, y = value)) +
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE, color = "red", size = 0.5, method = "loess") +
  facet_wrap( ~ name, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_classic() +
  
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Y")
```

[image]